# .htaccess - Block requests, based on referrer protocol (file)

Tags: .htaccess, cross-domain

I am having a web program.
Some of my clients, are saving pages into their hard drive instead of creating shortcuts.
When they are trying to use the system they are opening the html from their local hard drive.

This creates a lot of bugs because the js files and the data they are using is not up to date, and a lot of time they are not logged in.

We had enough getting customers calling about bugs in our system, while they are using this local html file.

I can't force them to re-download the files, so I wish to block requests to my server that are reffered by 'file://' protocol.

The users will have html page with no data cuss or images and we hopes this will make the go to the website...

And here are my questions:

1. How do you block any requests that originated by "file://" protocol?
2. Do you have better solution?

Comment: Well, if you can detect a request from such outdated copy, then wouldn't it make more sense to redirect the client, so that it automatically fetches the current version?

Comment: I can't detect..
I am having client error handler that sends me a lot of errors because of this HTML files.

Comment: Are you _really_ sure those are "local copies"? That would be a _very_ untypical behavior of users... Maybe those are just locally cached versions instead?

Comment: I am sure, I had remote logged in into multiple customers computers.

Comment: I don't really see a connection there, actually. But its OK if you say so. Pretty strange users, though.

Comment: Take a look at the `X-Frame-Options` header, it might help to prevent that such copies get used. Also the "same origin policy" headers might be worth a look. Both obviously assume that you deliver your pages via https using a validateable certificate.